# How to end a game in C# from a Collision

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is the current script that I have. I have a ball that is player, and I want a collision with my game object tagged as "pit" to end the game. When the game ends I want my game over canvas to pop up. The current script detects the hit when the player rolls over the pit, however, currently, nothing else happens. Both my player and pit have rigidbodies and colliders attached to them. I would really appreciate any help with how to get my code to work properly.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Trigger : MonoBehaviour
{
   public GameObject GameManager;

   private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
   {
      Debug.Log("hit detected")

      if(other.gameObject.tag == "pit")
      {
          GameManager.GetComponent<Game_Manager>().EndGame();
      }
   }
}
```

My EndGame code is in my GameManager script. The is the part of that script that deals with ending the game.

```
public void EndGame ()
{
    player.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().constraints =   RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePosition;
    hasGameStarted = true;
    inMenuUI.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    inGameUI.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    gameOverUI.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    
}
```

Comment: how is setup your player and "pit" rigidbody/colliders?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you show use the code for `EndGame`? Did you [debug](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html) and check if it is even getting called? In general rather use `other.CompareTag("pit")` .. it avoids silent fails by throwing an exception in case of a misspelled/non-existent tag

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct in interpreting your question, your script successfully detects player death already. If you want a game over screen you have a couple of options:

You can create a UI canvas with a panel on it that obscures the whole screen and put the words Game Over.

Or, probably the better option is to create an entirely new Unity scene and make the Game Over canvas there. When you want to trigger the game over screen you simply use:
Scene manager.LoadScene("Scene name");

You have to add "using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;" at the top of your script. Also note you have to add your Game Over scene to the list of scenes in you game. I believe this can be done by navigating to File>Build settings>scenes and then pressing add open scenes assuming the game over scene is open.